# Grey out nav buttons unless is_user_logged_in()

Tags: menus, css, navigation

I'd like to show my users some features I offer if they register in a special nav bar. I've created this for a logged in version and a logged out version:

```php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu',
        'container'      => '0',
        'fallback_cb'    => 'wp_page_menu',
        'echo'           => '0',
    ) );
    echo $menu;
} else {
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
        'container'      => '0',
        'fallback_cb'    => 'wp_page_menu',
        'echo'           => '0',
    ) );
    ?>
    <style>#menu-item-1046{opacity : 0.4; filter: alpha(opacity=40);}</style>
    <?php
    echo $menu;
}
```

I'm trying to grey out (disable but leave visible) nav buttons by ID. Obviously my CSS in there works but doesn't disable the button...

I tried `<script>$('#menu-item-1046').button('disable');</script>`  But I've barely dabbled in jQuery as of now.

Comment: Pure CSS or Javascript questions are off topic per the [faq], and that seems to be what you are looking for. A pure CSS or Javascript solution would provide no real security anyway. Anyone wishing access could undo anything you can do with CSS or Javascript. Rather than "grey out" the links you need to actually remove them at the PHP level before the page prints. Also, since it would involve filters and walkers, that would not be off-topic.

Comment: This have already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/577558/1329669

Comment: I don't understand why this one was close voted. Disabling shouldn't be done via CSS and there **is** a possible solution via `wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: What is that solution @kaiser, I also didn't specify that it needed to be CSS or JS. Tried to show what I've attempted first, then ask the community. I just needed a solution, PHP preferred. Thanks!

Comment: A custom walker for example. There're plenty of answers here filed under [tag:walker]. Just search through and update your question.

Comment: @TR3B is the button you want to disable a Custom Link?

Answer (score 1):

When you look [at the possible arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu), then you'll see that there's as well the option to add a custom nav menu `walker` class.

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

The walker would be implemented like this:

```
$walker = new WPSE90265_Nav_Menu_Walker();

wp_nav_menu( array( 
    # ...
    'walker' => $walker
    # ...
) );
```

It should extend the default nav menu walker so you only need to overwrite those methods that you need to redefine:

```
class WPSE90265_Nav_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )
    {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $output = str_replace( 
                 'class="'
                ,'disabled class="'
                ,$output
            );

        parent::start_el( $output, $item, $depth, $args, $id );
    }
}
```

Note, that the `disabled` argument will only work for specific HTML elements/tags. Please do a search on which it works and alter your walker according to it. You could as well try to add an `onClick="return false;"` inside the walker if it's not possible to use such tags.

Answer (score 0):

Because the menu item is not button so you can't use .button(disable); function, combine this code with your above css:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
     $('#menu-item-1046').click(function(){return false;});
});
```

Comment: This answer was "automatically flagged a low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please try to add explanation to your answers rather than just post raw code.